# "List index out of range" error when sorting data in csv files using python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have three .csv files and i would like python to sort the data in them. i have this code but when i launch it an error occurs. An error occurs in this line sort = sorted(csv1, key= operator.itemgetter(1)). The number at the end suppose to choose the column but it doesn't. I had this program on mac and it worked but when i launched it on windows it stopped working.

```html
import operator
import csv

decision= input("How would you like to view information? Type score or surname.")
decision1= input("What calss would you like to see? Type class1 or class2 or class3.")


if (decision == 'score' and decision1 == 'class1'):
    sample = open('class1.csv', 'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key= operator.itemgetter(0))
    for eachline in sort:
        print (eachline)

if (decision == 'surname' and decision1 == 'class1'):
    sample = open('class1.csv', 'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key= operator.itemgetter(1))
    for eachline in sort:
        print (eachline)

if (decision == 'score' and decision1 == 'class2'):
    sample = open('class2.csv', 'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key= operator.itemgetter(0))
    for eachline in sort:
        print (eachline)

if (decision == 'surname' and decision1 == 'class2'):
    sample = open('class2.csv', 'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key= operator.itemgetter(1))
    for eachline in sort:
        print (eachline)

if (decision == 'score' and decision1 == 'class3'):
    sample = open('class3.csv', 'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key= operator.itemgetter(0))
    for eachline in sort:
        print (eachline)

if (decision == 'surname' and decision1 == 'class3'):
    sample = open('class3.csv', 'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter = ',')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key= operator.itemgetter(1))
    for eachline in sort:
        print (eachline)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import operator
import csv

sorter = raw_input("Set sort method (score or surname): ")
classNumber = raw_input("Set class number (1, 2 or 3): ")

def print_sorted(sortMethod, classNumber):
    classFile = 'class' + str(classNumber) + '.csv'
    with open(classFile, 'r') as fh:
        csvData = csv.DictReader(fh)
        sortedCsvData = sorted(csvData, key=operator.itemgetter(sortMethod))
        for line in sortedCsvData:
            print line

print_sorted(sorter, classNumber)
```

You would want to add some sort of validation of the input set by the user before running the function though.

This won't error out if there is a value missing for a column.

Edit to say: If you are using python 3 then you need to change raw_input() above to be input()

Comment: It still gives me an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Computing/sorting.py", line 2, in <module>
    import csv
  File "H:/Computing\csv.py", line 13, in <module>
    in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_newfile, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'

Comment: Did you use the code above? I'm not using csv.reader it's using csv.DictReader, so that error doesn't make sense. Why are you specifying a delimeter='\t' if in the original example you used a comma? I don't think that's the same thing you're running.

Comment: Sorry, fixed up a syntax error as well, so copy again.

Comment: Any luck trying this out?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like at least one of your rows is missing a value for column 1. `csv.reader(sample)` returns a generator of lists, where each list corresponds to a row, and the length of each list corresponds to the number of comma-separated values in the given row. So a file with data like this:

```
   John,Smith
   Joe
   Jane,Doe
```

Would give you `(["John", "Smith"], ["Joe"], ["Jane", "Doe"])` when parsed by `csv.reader`.

The `sorted` function is breaking when `operator.itemgetter` tries to access an index (column) from one of the lists (rows) that doesn't exist. If you were sorting on column 1 in the above example,  your code would break because there is only 1 element in the list `["Joe"]`